# Propriedade multipart-file-size-threshold lançando exceção

Tags: spring, arquivo, spring-boot

Na versão `2.1.3` do SpringBoot, estou tomando a seguinte exceção: `Failed to bind properties under 'spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold' to org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize`

application.properties:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
```

Exceção lançada:

> Description:
>
> Failed to bind properties under
> 'spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold' to
> org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize:
>
> ```
> Property: spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold
> Value: 2KB 
> Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:24:46
> Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Update your application's configuration

Answer (score 0):

Fala André beleza!

Provavelmente tem um espaço em branco após o sinal de igual. Tem 2KB[e um ou mais espaços ao final], quando o Spring tenta ler a propriedade ele encara como uma String por causa do espaço. Esse erro também acontece quando setamos uma das letras como minúscula, elas precisam ser obrigatoriamente maiúsculas.

Pra te ajudar a encontrar os espaços em branco clique no botão Show Withespace Characters da sua IDE que ela vai destacar os espaços em branco como na linha 10. Se estiver usando o IntelliJ ou qualquer outra IDE vai precisar encontrar a funcionalidade equivalente nela.

[image: Show Withespace Characters]

Voc~e pode ver [mais detalhes sobre esse erro aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188430/upload-file-size-limit-in-spring-boot)